# Error:: VR_Video is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtual-reality, google-vr

I am trying to add 360 Video Viewer to my project. I am getting this error.

error: VR_Video is not abstract and does not override abstract method onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar) in OnSeekBarChangeListener

The  thing when I declare VR_Video as abstract it shows error in manifest file stating that the class is not concrete class

Following is my code:

```
package com.example.jal.jp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoEventListener;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView;

import java.io.IOException;

publicclass VR_Video extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final String STATE_PROGRESS = "state_progress";
    private static final String STATE_DURATION = "state_duration";
    private VrVideoView mVrVideoView;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private Button mVolumeButton;

    private boolean mIsPaused;
    private boolean mIsMuted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vr__video);

        initViews();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putLong(STATE_PROGRESS, mVrVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        outState.putLong(STATE_DURATION, mVrVideoView.getDuration());

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        long progress = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_PROGRESS);

        mVrVideoView.seekTo(progress);
        mSeekBar.setMax((int) savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_DURATION));
        mSeekBar.setProgress((int) progress);
    }
    public void onPlayPausePressed() {

    }

    public void onVolumeToggleClicked() {
        mIsMuted = !mIsMuted;
        mVrVideoView.setVolume(mIsMuted ? 0.0f : 1.0f);

    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if( fromUser ) {
            mVrVideoView.seekTo(progress);
        }
    }
    private void initViews() {
        mVrVideoView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        mVolumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_volume);
        mVrVideoView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());
        //try { VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options(); options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
          //  mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options); } catch( IOException e ) { //Handle exception }
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public  void onClick(View view) {
                onVolumeToggleClicked();
            }
        });
    }


    class VideoLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
                        //options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                        VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options(); options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                        mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        //Handle exception
                    }
                    //your code here


                }
            });


            return true;
        }

        }

    public void playPause() {
        if( mIsPaused ) {
            mVrVideoView.playVideo();
        } else {
            mVrVideoView.pauseVideo();
        }

        mIsPaused = !mIsPaused;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mVrVideoView.pauseRendering();
        mIsPaused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVrVideoView.resumeRendering();
        mIsPaused = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mVrVideoView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    private class ActivityEventListener extends VrVideoEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onLoadSuccess() {
            super.onLoadSuccess();
            mSeekBar.setMax((int) mVrVideoView.getDuration());
            mIsPaused = false;


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
            super.onLoadError(errorMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            super.onClick();
            playPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewFrame() {
            super.onNewFrame();
            mSeekBar.setProgress((int) mVrVideoView.getCurrentPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion() {
            super.onCompletion();
            mVrVideoView.seekTo(0);

        }

    }
}
```

Error Message:
C:\Users\Jal\Jp\app\src\main\java\com\example\jal\jp\VR_Video.java
Error:(18, 9) error: VR_Video is not abstract and does not override abstract method onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar) in OnSeekBarChangeListener
Incremental compilation of 3 classes completed in 14.478 secs.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: So... override the abstract method onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar) in OnSeekBarChangeListener then.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks..I am not really sure how to do that. I am very new to Android, trying to learn. Can you please show me ?